# Weighting function in boost::numeric::quadrature or gsl quadrature

Tags: c++, boost, gsl

I am trying to take the integral of a gamma PDF (pdf(x, a, b)) and apply a weighting function (w(x)).  I have been trying to find an example for either boost or gsl to do this in c++, but have come up short so far.

I was trying to use this as an input function in boost, but it doesnt not seem to work

```
struct f(a, b)
{
    double operator()(double x){ return w(x)*gamma_distribution(a, b) };

}
```

I am not 100% sure why though.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What happens when it "doesnt not seem to work"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax is wrong. Your snippet should be

```
struct f
{
    double operator()(double x) { return w(x)*gamma_distribution(a, b); }
};
```